# How to enable mysqld start logging

Tags: mysql

I'm starting MySQL Server on Windows via mysqld.exe and sometimes cmd console closed quickly and sometimes console stays open. 
I'm wondering is it possible to enable some loggin because in both cases there is nothing in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

log=query_log_file_name

In your my.ini file. For more information you can refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html